# c# error - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, android, sql

I have a WebService to get audio files sended by an android application but when I try to export then I get this error in the WebService:

```
2013-10-09 09:41:07,486 [18] ERROR Caderneta.ArquivosDAO 
  ArquivosDAO.cs: Falha -> InsertAudio
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@IdImagem".
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Caderneta.ArquivosDAO.InsertAudio(Audio arquivos, String idponto) in C:\Users\Leandro\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Caderneta\Caderneta\ArquivosDAO.cs:line 75
ClientConnectionId:b5e32e72-8c84-4585-8302-d3dd0681e23d
```

Here is the SQL command:

```
cmdInsertVoz.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Voz (IdVoz, IdPonto, IdContextoVoz, IdImagem, DadoVoz, FlagUpload, IdMovel) VALUES(@IDVOZ, @IDPONTO, @IDCONTEXTO, @IdImagem, @DADOSVOZ, 0, @IDMOVEL)";
```

And this is the method to insert the Audio:

```
public void InsertAudio(Audio arquivos, String idponto)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdInsertVoz.Transaction = tran;

                String IdVozes = criaId(idponto, 2);
                    cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDVOZ", IdVozes);

                    cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDPONTO", idponto);
                    cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCONTEXTO", Convert.ToInt32(arquivos.contexto));
                    if (IdVozes.Length == 11)
                    {
                        cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdImagem", IdVozes.Substring(0, 9));
                    }

                    byte[] vozBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(arquivos.arquivo);
                    cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DADOSVOZ", vozBytes);
                    cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDMOVEL", arquivos.idmovel);
                    cmdInsertVoz.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    log.Info("exec");
                    cmdInsertVoz.Parameters.Clear();
                    log.Debug("gravado arquivo de áudio");

            }catch(Exception e){

                this.log.Error("ArquivosDAO.cs: Falha -> InsertAudio", e);
                throw e;
            }

        }
```

I'm realy stucked in this error and have no idea what I'm doing wrong in this case.

Comment: i bet your `if` statement doesn't evaluate to `true` and `IdImagem` doesn't get set.  In your case you'll need a default value to assign the `IdImagem` parameter, or the query will fail.

Comment: What is the value of `IdVozes`?

Comment: Following on from what Jonesy said, you should check all this yourself first by stepping into the code during debugging and checking the lines you'd expect to get hit are in fact getting hit.

Comment: If `IdVozes.Length` is always equal to `11`, you don't need the if. If it *can* be (and is in this case) unequal, you have the problem.

Comment: Ok I'll try to set a default value to IdImagem and see what happens.

Comment: @Corak actually the IdVozes will only have length equals to 11 if it's related to an image, this is why I need the if.

Comment: @TiagoGeanezini - Yes, and as you seem to have realized, if the length is unequal to `11`, then you don't provide a parameter and a value for `@IdImagem` and get the exception you got.

Comment: That's true. How I didn't notice that. I'll try to fix it now